# How can $\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle=\langle 1_{12}\rangle$ be true?

Tags: group-theory

> Determine the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$
>
> **a)**$\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle$

*Resolution*

$\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle=\langle 1_{12}\rangle=\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

**Question:**

How can $\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle=\langle 1_{12}\rangle$? I have been searching for theorems that may state $(a,b)=c\in G$, but I found nothing.
What results do imply $\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle=\langle 1_{12}\rangle$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $x\in H$, then $\langle x\rangle\subseteq H$.

Now use $H=\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle$ and $1_{12}=3_{12}-2_{12}\in H$.

Since $\langle 1_{12}\rangle=\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, you're done.

### Note

The symbol $\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle$ means *the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ generated by the two elements $2_{12}$ and $3_{12}$*. It has nothing to do with “vectors” or direct products. In particular,
$$
\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle=
\{ a 2_{12}+b 3_{12}: a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \}
$$
Similarly
$$
\langle 1_{12}\rangle=
\{ a 1_{12}: a\in\mathbb{Z} \}
=\mathbb{Z}_{12}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am having hard time understand the step $1_{12}=3_{12}-2_{12}$. What reason or proposition backs up that step?

Comment: @PedroGomes: $1+2=3$

Comment: @celtschk                 I am studying direct products, and I am treating $(a,b)$ as vector. Therefore it is difficult for me to see why I can have $b-a$. I understand the arithmetic aspect of the operation.

Comment: @PedroGomes What direct product are you thinking of here? I think your notation is confusing between the generators of a subgroup and the components of a direct product. You need to clarify your question and make sure that your notation is consistent with the question you really want to ask.

Comment: @MarkBennet                  The notation is not mine. I have been studying direct products, and the notation that has been adopted in the material I am studying is the following: if $a\in G_1,b\in G_2, (a,b)\in G_1\times G_2$. If we have a cyclic group, let´s suppose $Z=G_1\times G_2$, then there is a generator of that group that can be written as $\langle a,b\rangle$, for $a,b\in Z$. Is it clear now? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @PedroGomes It is clear, but the elements $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$. Your $G$ is $\mathbb Z_{12}$ and you have made $a$ and $b$ elements of that group. If you are trying to prove $\mathbb Z_{12}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_4$ that is one thing. If you are trying to do this taking generators of subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ then you need to take $4$ rather than $2$ as a generator. As it stands the product you seem to be describing is not a direct product because $2\times 3=3\times 2 \neq 0$

Comment: My problem lies in the fact I do not know why $3_{12}-2_{12}$ this operation can be conducted? As far as I remember $\langle a \rangle=\{a^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. On this case we would have $\langle a \rangle=\{(2_{12},3_{12})^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Why can I make operations with the two elements? What proposition backs up that operation? I think now I am being clearer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's not a vector. $\langle 2_{12},3_{12}\rangle$ is not equal to $\langle (2_{12},3_{12})\rangle$ but it is a (slight) abuse of the notation $\langle \{2_{12},3_{12}\}\rangle$

Comment: @stevengregory Are you saying this can be interpreted as a set ${2_{12},3_{12}}$?

Comment: the subgroup generated by the two elements $2_{12}$ and $3_{12}$. And it's an additive group, not a multiplicative group.